# Powershell sorting array into multi-dimensional array with the “-like” comparison operator

Tags: powershell, multidimensional-array

I'am trying to collect my array into a multidimensional array by using the `-like` comparison operator for further processing.

I wrote the following array loop but i cannot replace `"*kw1*"` with `"*$keyword[$j]*"`. It will break the operator validation.

```
$keywords = @("kw1", "kw2")
$list = @("name_kw1_000", "name_kw1_001", "name_kw1_002", "name_kw2_000", "name_kw2_001", "name_kw2_002")


$mdarr= New-Object object[][] $keywords.Length
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $list.Length; ++$i) {
    for ($j = 0; $j -lt $keywords.Length; ++$j) {
        if ( $list[$i] -like "*kw1*" ) {
            $mdarr[$j] += $list[$i];
        }
    }
}
```

My expected output is:

```
$mdarr[0]
name_kw1_000
name_kw1_001
name_kw1_002
$mdarr[1]
name_kw2_000
name_kw2_001
name_kw2_002
```

Is this possible with the above array loop or would i have to do this completely different since the `-like` operator does not seem to be array friendly.

Comment: Can you explain your question and desired output a little bit more? If I run your code sample it actually outputs what you are asking. If I output $mdarr[0] I only get the "kw1" results on screen, same for $mdarr[1].

Comment: You're expecting elements with `kw2` in the resulting array but never check for it.

Comment: bluuf, the expected output is in my post.
montonero, yes, that is my question. the `"*$keyword[$j]*"` cannot be used like expected because of the wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean to get output for a variable length array, using more keywords.
As [montonero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7419215/montonero) comments, you never test if the keyword is actually part of the item in the list of words.

Maybe this will help:

```
# there is no need to enclose the items with '@()'
$keywords = "kw1", "kw2"
$list = "name_kw1_000", "name_kw1_001", "name_kw1_002", "name_kw2_000", "name_kw2_001", "name_kw2_002"

# in case your keywords contain characters that have special meaning
# for regex '-match', we should escape these characters.
$keywords = $keywords | ForEach-Object { [RegEx]::Escape($_) }

# fill the object array
$mdarr= New-Object object[][] $keywords.Count
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $keywords.Count; $i++) {
    foreach ($item in $list) {
        if ($item -match $keywords[$i]) {
            $mdarr[$i] += $item
        }

    }
}

# write result
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $mdarr.Count; $i++) {
    Write-Host ("`$mdarr[$i]") -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $mdarr[$i]
}
```

This will output

> ```
> $mdarr[0]
> name_kw1_000
> name_kw1_001
> name_kw1_002
> $mdarr[1]
> name_kw2_000
> name_kw2_001
> name_kw2_002
> ```